# "Go off" vs. "go" when describing an event

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

I don't hear "go off" very often used in conjunction with "event" to mean "to happen." What is the **difference** between

> It's amazing that our party went off so well!

and

> It's amazing that our party went so well!

Is it a BrE/AmE thing?

Answer (score 1):

***[Go off](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/go-off)*** is used idiomatically with the meaning of:

​

> to happen in a particular way:
>
> - The protest march went off peacefully.

[To go](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/go) is used similarly with the following meaning:

> to result or end; turn out:
>
> - How did the game go?

To sum up, the two expression are very close in meaning.

Answer (score -1):

A party "going off so well" strikes me as a rather old-fashioned way of speaking. I imagine a rather grand old lady (a dowager duchess, perhaps) saying such a thing. (The word "off" would be pronounced "orf" by such a lady.)
The problem with going off is that exactly the same phrase is used in respect of a foodstuff that has become rotten or sour: "the milk has gone off, so you will have to manage without". Best avoided.